# Converting tripack::tri.mesh output into a sf_linestring

Tags: r, r-sf

Running tripack::tri.mesh on a set of geospatial points will create a Delaunay triangulation of the set.

```
points <- data.frame(
     lat1=c(-26.3, -27.1, -26.8),
     long1=c(27.3, 28.5, 28.2),
     lat2=c(-26.5, -26.9, -27.2),
     long2=c(28.3, 27.5, 28.1)) 

points <- sf::st_as_sf(points, coords = c("long1","lat1"), remove = FALSE)

mesh <- tripack::tri.mesh(x = sf::st_coordinates(points[,1])[,1],
     y = sf::st_coordinates(points[,1])[,2])
```

The output will be a triangulation object composed of several arguments.

How can I convert this output into an sf linestring object connecting the spatial points?

Comment: do you just want the points - e.g. `sfheaders::sf_linestring(obj = as.data.frame(mesh[c("x","y")]), x = "x", y = "y")` ?

Answer (score 1):

Delaunay triangulation can also be created with `{sf}`, it uses *GEOS*  implementation. Union of points should be created first. To return lines instead of polygons, we can set `bOnlyEdges` attribute of `st_triangulate()` and resulting `MULTILINESTRING` can be converted to `LINESTRING`s, if needed:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
points <- data.frame(
  lat1=c(-26.3, -27.1, -26.8),
  long1=c(27.3, 28.5, 28.2),
  lat2=c(-26.5, -26.9, -27.2),
  long2=c(28.3, 27.5, 28.1)) 

points <- st_as_sf(points, coords = c("long1","lat1"), remove = FALSE)

tri_edges <- points |>
  st_union() |> 
  st_triangulate(bOnlyEdges = TRUE) |> 
  st_cast("LINESTRING")
tri_edges
#> Geometry set for 3 features 
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 27.3 ymin: -27.1 xmax: 28.5 ymax: -26.3
#> CRS:           NA
#> LINESTRING (28.2 -26.8, 28.5 -27.1)
#> LINESTRING (27.3 -26.3, 28.2 -26.8)
#> LINESTRING (27.3 -26.3, 28.5 -27.1)

plot(tri_edges, col = 1:3, lwd = 2)
plot(st_geometry(points), pch = 16, cex = 1, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is great, thank you. Would you know how to add breaklines? For example, if points are located in a body of water, the LINESTRINGs cannot span over islands. The points that make the contour of the islands would be identified. If this needs to be another question, simply let me know and I can repost.

Comment: I think the question here should be bit more application-specific,  like "how to handle barriers while finding shortest paths on plane/sphere".  Which in turn might lead to some well-established design patterns or packages like https://github.com/jsta/ipdw or https://agrdatasci.github.io/gdistance/ . But I guess what you ask is not that difficult with just `sf` either, though it probably would not include `st_triangulate(bOnlyEdges = TRUE)` . I'd go with another question, just try to include some sample data, both points and polygons, and provide a desired output, which could be just a sketch.

Comment: Perfect, thanks again. I might have found a potential way forward with RCDT but will post another question if that does not work out.